# Creating Sequence numbers with same letters eitherside

Tags: vba, list, button, sequence

How to create sequential numbers at end of a list with letters either side, It's always MW....A, so changing the middle number? can this be done using a button so when clicked these are created at the bottom of the list.
Thanks

Comment: Yes, it can be done! But what did you try in order to solve your problem? Maybe we will understand more looking to your  code. In what range to be the inserted number? Must they be incremented according to a rule?

Comment: I couldn't find a suitable VBA, I have tried using formula's and the fill tool in editing

Comment: This is basic... In what range to be the inserting numbers? Meaning, starting from what up to what value? Where the string obtain in the way you say must be returned? In a cells range? Somewhere else?

Comment: MW1668A, MW1669A, MW1670A is the order and I would like it to have no limits, adding the next 10 in order when clicking a button. The Cell the first one will go into is A155 (Previous ones were created manually) the going down the column e.g. A156, A157.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, please:

It will add `maxInc` units to the existing `startNo` value, for the range starting from the `lastRow` row...

```
Sub testIncrementValString()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, i As Long, lastRow As Long, startNo As Long, maxInc As Long
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
   maxInc = 10: startNo = 1670: lastRow = 155
   For i = 1 To maxInc
    sh.Range("A" & lastRow + i).Value = "MW" & startNo + i & "A"
   Next i
End Sub
```

The code can be adapted to find the last number inside the string, of the last filled row of A:A column and add a unit, or how many you need for the following...

Like this:

```
Sub testIncrementValString_bis()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, i As Long, lastRow As Long, startNo As Long, maxInc As Long
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here your sheet
   lastRow = sh.Range("A" & sh.Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
   startNo = CLng(Mid(sh.Range("A" & lastRow).Value, 3, _
                   Len(sh.Range("A" & lastRow).Value) - 3))
   maxInc = 10
   For i = 1 To maxInc
    sh.Range("A" & lastRow + i).Value = "MW" & startNo + i & "A"
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah that works to create them, Thankyou!! is there a way to make it continuous and create the next 10 numbers every time a button is clicked? as this only creates the 10 numbers after 1670. Thanks

Comment: @Hsmith: Yes, this I wast trying to say in the last two rows... Updated the answer with the new version.

Comment: Welcome! It will work until you will use more then 4 digits number. I will adapt te code to calculate the necessary number and work forever. Done! It now calculates the necessary digits to be returned for the `Mid` function...